# dd an internal partition to a single file onto an external USB drive

Tags: partitioning, dd, copy

#### Description:

I would like to copy a whole data partition (~100 GB) from a computer to a single file on an external USB drive so that I can copy it back on a new empty data partition of an other computer.

The external drive is 1.5 TB and already contains 1 TB of data which I do not want to lose.

So I would like to be able to specify the `of` option of the `dd` command as a **file** onto this disk rather than its `/dev/sdX` identifier (which otherwise would overwrite the existing data on it).

#### Question:

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to specify an output file (such as .iso, .img, .bak) by first mounting the device you want to write to, then running `sudo dd if=/dev/sdX# of=/mount/point/file.iso`. `dd` will automatically translate the partition into one of those filetypes, and won't just write it to the device directly.

Then, when finished, create a new empty partition of the appropriate size and run `sudo dd if=/mount/point/file.iso of=/dev/sdX#` and it will restore the partition.

If you prefer a GUI way, you can also use the gnome-disks utility to create a backup image of the partition you want to save; it does essentially the same thing as the `dd` command, but without the command line.

Comment: `$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdX# of=/mount/point/file.iso` <- do this also apply if the mount point of the external drive is `/media/username/USBDiskStorage` and the internal Data partition is mounted at `/media/username/Data`?

Comment: assuming the external drive (which you want to write TO) is `/media/username/Data` and the partition (which you want to write FROM) is `/dev/sdb1`, the command would be `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/media/username/Data`.